# express serverless configure lambda function

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have created a new lambda function.
when I do

```
serverless deploy
```

I tried like below

```
serverless deploy function -f myFunction
```

But it says does not exist in this service

it is uploading in existing function, where to change the configuration to hit new lamdba function

Thanks

Comment: Would you mind to provide the exact error message, please?

Comment: does not exist in this service

Comment: please add your serverless.yml file here